# Derivative of $\frac{x}{f(x)}\frac{df}{dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Suppose we have a function $f(x):\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ that satisfies:

1) $0\leq\frac{df}{dx} \leq 1$

2) $f(0) = 0$,

then do we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{f(x)}\frac{df}{dx} \right)\leq 0?$$

Comment: Interesting problem, but what are your thoughts?

Comment: @Ahaan Rungta : I'm quite sure the answer is yes. Based on the conditions, $x/f(x) \geq 1$

Comment: Are you asking about the statement for *all* $x$ or just at $x=0$?

Comment: for all $x\in \mathbb R^+$

Comment: Hint: $$ \text{LHS} = \frac {x}{f(x)} \cdot \frac {\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + \frac {\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot \frac {f(x) - x \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}}{\left[ f(x) \right]^2}. $$

Comment: Yes, I agree. By the way, do you notice how the LHS is undefined at $x=0$?

Comment: Because of the squared term in the denominator of the second summand?

Comment: Because $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't imply that the limit as $x\to 0$ is undefined.

Comment: In your post, you do not qualify it as a limit.

Comment: That's true $  $

Comment: Introducing $X = \log x$ and $Y = \log f$ we can restate the problem as follows: Given with $0\leq \frac{dY}{dX} \leq e^{X-Y}$ show that $\frac{d^2 Y}{dX^2} \leq 0$ i.e. that $Y$ is concave. The condition $f(0) = 0$ becomes $\lim_{X\to -\infty} Y(X)= -\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't look right near $0$. Take for example $y = \frac{x + x^2}{2}$, $0 \leq x \leq 0.25$ - This satisfies everything near $0$. But $(\frac{xy'}{y})' = \frac{1}{1+x^2} > 0$.

Comment: Your example can easily be extended to a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ by taking $y = \frac{x+x^2}{2}$ for $x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $y = \frac{3x+1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}e^{\frac{1}{2}-x}$ for $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$.